# Music Sound Design Thesis Ideas!

Tags: sound-design, sound, synthesizer, daw, synthesis

I'm about to start my thesis and I'm a bit confused as what to start with. I like to make music in my free time so I thought it would be a good opportunity to learn more about sound design in the field of music production eg sound synthesis, programs like Serum, synthsizers like Jupiter, etc. Coming up with a thesis statement better than "How software has changed music and why sound design is awesome" isn't quite the one I'm looking for lol any ideas, help, or material would be great. Thanks!

Comment: For future people with this same issue, check out this thesis: https://skemman.is/handle/1946/31029?locale=en

It's a "brief history of EDM production".

Comment: Does the person with the winning answer get the academic degree?  **Isn't the point of a thesis to demonstrate the comprehensive knowledge obtained from focusing all *your* time and effort   on the subject you have been studying?** Presumably  a thesis is  to express what YOU think and why you think it.

Comment: In addition to Alaska Man's point, let me add, that there should always be a person at your educational facility whose job is to mentor you during this project. Often they have a list of topics, since during their own research they discover connected questions, which are worth to be researched on, yet they don't have time to do it themselves. This site is certainly the wrong place to ask for topics because we don't even know the requirements of your thesis, the most important one being about how much time you have (months vs years).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a challenge try 'A taxonomy of voltage controlled filters'. e.g.

- Transistor ladder filter
- Diode ladder filter
- Sallen-Key filter
- OTA filter
- Exceptions

Comment: This is actually a really good idea especially when it comes to modular synthesis. But how to make this into a thesis or, better put, how can one make a good thesis statement out of this?

Comment: Something like: Although there are very many different electronic music synthesizers it is popularly recognised that essentially there is a limited variety of the voltage controlled filter (VCF) component. This thesis presents a classification of these VCFs according to their fundamental design types.

Comment: Yes, but this is stating a fact. There's nothing here to dispute that would turn it into a thesis, no? This is simply stating something that is already fact. If, however, it could be argued that there is in fact an *unlimited* variety, then I think it could easily be turned into a 30 page report. Maybe I'm looking at this wrong? I don't know much about this topic.